# WebView shell has stopped on a system image built from AOSP

Tags: android, webview, chromium, android-source

I follow the instructions [here](https://source.android.com/setup/build/building) to build Android. Everything works and I can launch the emulator successfully. However, whenever I reach a screen that contains a WebView, the app crashes with a message "WebView shell has stopped". Here is some of the output from logcat

```
04-19 19:31:29.694  2234  2234 I cr_BrowserStartup: Initializing chromium process, singleProcess=true
04-19 19:31:29.721  2234  2234 F chromium: [FATAL:gpu_info_collector_android.cc(193)] failed to create a pbuffer surface for fetching driver strings. EGL_SUCCESS (3000)
--------- beginning of crash
04-19 19:31:29.735  2254  2234 F google-breakpad: -----BEGIN BREAKPAD MICRODUMP-----
04-19 19:31:29.735  2254  2234 F google-breakpad: V WebView:52.0.2743.100
04-19 19:31:29.735  2254  2234 F google-breakpad: O A x86 01 i686 Android/aosp_x86/generic_x86:7.0/NBD92G/xxxx04191749:eng/test-keys
04-19 19:31:29.736  2254  2234 F google-breakpad: G UNKNOWN
04-19 19:31:29.736  2254  2234 F google-breakpad: H 12C00000 BF859000 0017 56AEE000 82D22000 0C:06 0D:07 0E:01 0F:02 10:01 11:02 12:01 1B:01 1C:01 1E:01
```

I built the Android source on a CentOS server. I built Android 7.0. The built system image should be correct because if I move it to my Macbook, everything works including WebView.

Can anyone tells me what I should do to make it behave correctly on the Server? Thanks!

Comment: Traced the error message, looks like it failed after calling `eglCreatePbufferSurfaceFn`: https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src.git/+/62.0.3178.1/gpu/config/gpu_info_collector_android.cc#195 I don't do Chromium development on Android but you might want to research more on that method

Comment: Thanks for your comments. I have posted the answer below. It is caused by the wrong AVDs

Answer (score 1):

I have resolved the problem by creating an SDK with `sdkmanager`. I manually download the `emulator`, `platforms`, `platform-tools`, and `system-images` that are the necessary parts of an SDK. Then I use the `avdmanager` to create an AVD with x86 system image for API level 24 (with Google APIs). Before launching the AVD, I replace the `system.img` and `randisk.img` with the images I built from the Android source. That's all.